# CefSharp background extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cefsharp

I want to load a Chrome extension in a CefSharp browser.
I know that extensions are different in CefSharp.

I'm using the CefSharp example in the official github to try load my extension.
I have the set_color extension as an example from CefSharp, but it's not a background extension.

My extension requires to be in background with the manifest key "background".
How can I do this ? How can I load my background extension in CefSharp ?

I haven't seen web requests or web navigation API in the API list of CefSharp JS.
Is the list updated ? Or is there another way to have these API events ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extension support is very limited, very few extensions work currently. What extension are you using? Can you implement the same behaviour using JavaScript? Depending on the complexity this is sometimes an option. Version 102 will hopefully allow support for the chrome runtime which does have extension support, you can subscribe to  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3469#discussioncomment-2589397 for updates on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I'm expecting to have webRequests or webNavigation events. I want also tabs events when they are updated.
If I understand, the background extension will be available in the next version, but do you know when will be the release of the version 102 ?

Comment: That's an over simplification, I'd suggest subscribing to the discussion on GitHub, I'll post more details when available. I'd expect an official 102 release in 2-3 weeks. CI builds should be available for testing early/mid next week https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp#releases-1

Comment: I will subscribe to the GitHub discussion, thank you.

Comment: Where I can find the content of the next release ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You mentionned the 102 release, what will be the main features in this release?

Comment: You can review the CEF commits at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/commits/branch/5005 for the CEF changes. You can subscribe to release only notifications on GitHub https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp and read the release notes when the actual release is ready.

Comment: Than you. 
Do you know why I can't register to the Cef forum ?
I've never received the mail to validate my registration.

Comment: Try https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/2962/unable-to-register-in-your-forums#comment-57861660 I'm not involved with running ceforum, so cannot help past that